Bound of an integral function
Let $$f(r):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{2\pi i \langle x,y\rangle}e^{-|y|^4+r^{1/2}|y|^2}dy\right|dx,$$
for $r\geq 0$.
Is it possible to uniformly bound $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$? i.e.
$$\exists c>0,\forall r>0,f(r)\leq c$$
if not, can we do it on intervals $r \in [0,U]$? That is, do you have $\sup_{r\in[0,U]}f(r)<\infty$?
Tried writing Taylor expression for cosine and exponential but this seems to complicate the problem.
Using Fourier transform properties we do have that for $r\in[0,U],h_r(y):=e^{-|y|^4+r^{1/2}|y|^2},c=\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}1/(|x|+1)^{1+d}dx$,
$$\begin{align*}
f(r) &\leq c\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R^d}}|(1+|x|)^{1+d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-2\pi i \langle x,y\rangle}e^{-|y|^4+r^{1/2}|y|^2}dy| \\
&\leq c\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d}\sum_{k_1+...+k_{d+1}=d+1}c_{k_1,...,k_{d+1}}|\prod_{q=1}^kx_q^{k_q}\hat{h}_r(x_1,...,x_d)| \\
&\leq \sum_{k_1+...+k_{d+1}=d+1}c'_{k_1,...,k_{d+1}}\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}\partial^{k_1}_{x_1}...\partial_{x_d}^{k_d}h_r(x)dx.
\end{align*}$$
Would this lead to a bound on $[0,U]$?

Yes, your method would lead to a bound on $[0,U]$. The decay of the Fourier transform of a function is controlled by its smoothness, so you should expect to need to take derivatives in order to control the $L^1$ norm. For this reason I don’t think a global bound is possible.

Your bound works on $[0,U]$. As for a bound on $\mathbb R_+$, the answer is no.
Two changes of variable allow you to write
$$ f(r) = \int_{\mathbb R^d} \left| \int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{2i\pi \langle x,y\rangle} e^{r g(y)} \mathrm d y \right| \mathrm d x $$
with $g(y) = -|y|^4 + |y|^2$.
For $1/2<|y|<0.9$ we have $g(y) \geq 1/7$, and for $|x|<1/3$ and $|y|<1$ we have $\Re(e^{-2\pi i \langle x,y\rangle}) \geq 1/2$. Since $g(y)\geq 0$ for $|y|\leq 1$, we have
$$\Re \int_{|y|\leq 1} e^{2i\pi \langle x,y\rangle} e^{r g(y)} \mathrm d y \geq \mathrm{cste} \ e^{r/7} , $$
where cste denotes a positive numerical value that can be computed, that may depend on $d$ but not on $r$.
On the other hand, assuming $r\geq 1$ and using that $t^2-t^4 \leq -2(t-1)$ for $t\geq 1$,
$$ \left| \int_{|y|\geq 1} e^{2i\pi \langle x,y\rangle} e^{r g(y)} \mathrm d y \right| \leq \mathrm{cste} \int_1^\infty t^{d-1} e^{-2 (t-1)} \mathrm d t \leq \mathrm{cste} . $$
Then, writing $B(u)$ for the set of all $y$ with $|y|<u$,
$$ f(r) \geq \int_{B(1/3)} \int_{B(0.9)\setminus B(0.5)} (\mathrm{cste}\ e^{r/7} - \mathrm{cste}) \mathrm d y \mathrm d x \geq \mathrm{cste} \ e^{r/7} - \mathrm{cste} . $$
So, no, you cannot bound $f$ uniformly on $\mathbb R_+$.
